# How to collapse border right of div A with border left of div B to have single border

Tags: css

My title might not really say much about what i want to achive i dont really know how to put this buti hope with some explanation you guys will know what mean
I have some divs that are float left next to each other, i gave border of 1px to all the divs and a realize that the result is not so nice because at the middle the left border of element on right side collide with the right border of element in the left side therefore make the border look so think i want a collapse border right of div A with border left of div B to have single border   all through, i try to add a custom css to remove the border for those div in middle but it doesn't look nice like i want it, below is my code any help will be apppreciate

https://jsfiddle.net/c4nbs88e/2/

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3  groceries_right_mobile">

  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Intsant Noddle buttered bread you will like
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>

    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile g_item_mobile_border">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Intel-mobile-A45 castol
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>

    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Tecno - Spark k798 model
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>

    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Intsant Noddle buttered bread you will like
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>

    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile g_item_mobile_border">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Intsant Noddle buttered bread you will like
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>

    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Intsant Noddle buttered bread you will like
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>

    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Intel-mobile-A45 castol
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>

    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile g_item_mobile_border">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Tecno - Spark k798 model
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>

    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Intel-mobile-A45 castol
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>

    </div>
  </a>

</div>
</div>

          .col-nopadding {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.groceries_right_mobile {
  min-height: 400px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  width:600px;
  padding:20px !important;
}

.groceries_right_mobile a,
.groceries_right_mobile a:hover {
  color: #333;
}


.g_item_mobile {
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px !important;
  background-color: #fff;
  width:150px;
  float: left;

}

.groceries_popular_title_mobile {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}

.-ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.groceries_popular_price_mobile {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ca2486;
  float: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.g_item_mobile_border{
    border-left: 0 !important;
    border-right: 0 !important;
    border-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: A negative margin equal to the border size will do : `.g_item_mobile {
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px !important;
  background-color: #fff;
  width:150px;
  float: left;
  margin-right:-1px;
  margin-bottom:-1px;

}` https://jsfiddle.net/c4nbs88e/3/ botom could be also taken care of . **alternative :** use `box-shadow:0 0 0 1px #ddd;` they will overlap https://jsfiddle.net/c4nbs88e/4/ *I can turn this into an answer if this is it.

Comment: @ G-Cyr  thanks so much for your help this work as expected, you can turn this to answer i will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a negative margin to swallow an equal border-size on the right and bottom sides or a shadow .

- with border you could do : `margin-right:-1px;`

```css
.col-nopadding {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.groceries_right_mobile {
  min-height: 400px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  width:600px;
  padding:20px !important;
}

.groceries_right_mobile a,
.groceries_right_mobile a:hover {
  color: #333;
}


.g_item_mobile {
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px !important;
  background-color: #fff;
  width:150px;
  float: left;
  margin-right:-1px;
  margin-bottom:-1px;

}

.groceries_popular_title_mobile {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}

.-ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.groceries_popular_price_mobile {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ca2486;
  float: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3  groceries_right_mobile">
  
  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Intsant Noddle buttered bread you will like
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>
      
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile g_item_mobile_border">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Intel-mobile-A45 castol
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>
     
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Tecno - Spark k798 model
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>
     
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Intsant Noddle buttered bread you will like
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>
      
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile g_item_mobile_border">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Intsant Noddle buttered bread you will like
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>
     
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Intsant Noddle buttered bread you will like
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>
     
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Intel-mobile-A45 castol
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>
      
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile g_item_mobile_border">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Tecno - Spark k798 model
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>
      
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Intel-mobile-A45 castol
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>
     
    </div>
  </a>

</div>
</div>
```

- or fake the border with a shadow wich will overlap anything standing close aside : `box-shadow:0 0 0 1px #ddd;`

```css
.col-nopadding {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.groceries_right_mobile {
  min-height: 400px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  width:600px;
  padding:20px !important;
}

.groceries_right_mobile a,
.groceries_right_mobile a:hover {
  color: #333;
}


.g_item_mobile {
  height: 150px;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px #ddd;
  padding: 8px !important;
  background-color: #fff;
  width:150px;
  float: left;

}

.groceries_popular_title_mobile {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}

.-ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.groceries_popular_price_mobile {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ca2486;
  float: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3  groceries_right_mobile">
  
  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Intsant Noddle buttered bread you will like
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>
      
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile g_item_mobile_border">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Intel-mobile-A45 castol
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>
     
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Tecno - Spark k798 model
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>
     
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Intsant Noddle buttered bread you will like
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>
      
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile g_item_mobile_border">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Intsant Noddle buttered bread you will like
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>
     
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Intsant Noddle buttered bread you will like
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>
     
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Intel-mobile-A45 castol
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>
      
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile g_item_mobile_border">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Tecno - Spark k798 model
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>
      
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="  g_item_mobile">
      <p class="groceries_popular_title_mobile -ellipsis">Intel-mobile-A45 castol
      </p>
      <span class="groceries_popular_price_mobile">₦ 200</span>
     
    </div>
  </a>

</div>
</div>
```